# SSLVPN client saving encrypted password in local xml file, is that secure?

Tags: password-management

Simply copy the specific xml file to another client's correspond path, I can login to the remote network automatically. If that is a vulnerability, what severity rate will you give to it? High, medium, or low? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's potentially a vulnerability. As to how severe, it depends on how that file is protected (ACL, encryption)

Comment: @Stephane how about no ACL no encryption?

Comment: no ACl at all? Like in "everyone read" ? If that's the case (and that isn't a consequence of performing a non-default install) then it would probably rate medium: locally exploitable, requiring authentication on the target machine

Comment: @Stephane professional!